# conferring - to confer - meaning

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm from Brazil and here the word **confer** (conferir) has the same meaning as **check**.

But in the dictionaries online I couldn't find this meaning in its definition:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/confer
https://www.wordreference.com/definition/conferring

So, in the following phrase, for example:

*I'm conferring the numbers of the product in stock and as soon as possible I'll give you a feedback*

Could I use it this way? Is it correct?

thanks in advance

Comment: You probably mean 'confirm'. 'I'm confirming the numbers who are coming' means 'I'm checking that we've got the number of people coming right.'

Comment: Why don't you believe the dictionary? Bear in mind: to confer meaning on something. outorgar sentido a algo. Também, consultar uma pessoa, discutir com ela.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm sorry, it's hard to trust in the dictionary sometimes XD There was a time with another word that a specific entry wasn't present in two dictionaries, but was present in another. And also google translator had this meaning to confer! Which reminds me that I have to send a correction suggestion in there.

Comment: My advice? Forget google translate. The best overall dictionary is Collins. They have zero mistakes but it is not extensive. Michaelis is better now but really still not very good.

Comment: Really!? Thanks by the tip!! Usually I "confer" with the Cambridge Dictionary or with the Merriam Webster Dictionary more, but I'm going to check Collins more often then!

Answer (score 1):

No, you would not be able to use it that way in English. Confer means specifically to discuss with someone else, or exchange opinions or ask for advice. You could say something like

> I'm unsure what products we have in stock, but I will confer with our warehouse manager and get back to you.

You would be able to use "check" in place of confer in that example ("I will check with our warehouse manager") which is perhaps where some confusion could arise. If you were going to check the stock yourself, though, you would not be able to use confer.

I don't speak Portuguese myself, but if as you say "conferir" can mean check in all its meanings this could be an example of a [False Friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) - a word that sounds like it should mean the same thing in another language, but doesn't.

Comment: + 1 Yes, it is a false friend, and using confer for conferir is **a translation error**. I do speak Portuguese,,,,

Comment: woa! I would never expect that with such a common word!! English can be very specific sometimes XD  thanks a lot!!!

Comment: but technically the word is a half false friend or half true friend, because of its other meanings, like bestow, or when you have to "conferir" about something with someone else, it works the same way as in Portuguese XD

Comment: also, let me take advantage of this thread and also ask: Could I say then that I'm going to confer something with myself? Like I'm talking with my inner self?